# Restore and Backup Hypervisors

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v

So, I have two hypervisors (**Hyper-V** and **VMWare ESXi**) running on bare metal in two diferent machines.

What I need is to make an installation and configuration in two other machines with the same exact configurations.

The configurations in those hypervisors are vital and complex and I can't think of any other solution other then installing them from the start, wich would take a lot of time.

They are managed by Red Hat CloudForms, witch also makes some configurations in the network easier.

The ideal would be to backup those hypervisors and restore them in the other machines, but it will most likely give a bunch of drivers errors.

Is there another way to clone the hypervisors ? Any advice is more then welcome.

Comment: What's you actual question here?

Comment: @Gregl, I have updated the post

Comment: It is better to automate the installation and configuration of your hypervisor. Then you can install as many identical hypervisors as you wish with a single click of the mouse...

Comment: For ESXi you'll want to look into Host Profiles (requires vCenter Server AFAIK). For Hyper-V you'll want to look into Physical Computer Profiles (requires SCVMM AFAIK).

Comment: @MichaelHampton, i don't think automation is the way. Like i said the configuration is very complex and it wasn't me who has configured it, i would probably take the same amount of time or more scripting it.

Comment: @joeqwerty, i will take a look at the Profiles in more detail to see if it will help

Comment: That's what the person before you said, and look what a mess it's landed you in. This probably won't be the only time you have to provision another hypervisor. Even if you only have to provision two of them, ever, automating it in advance will save you time and money. Do it right this time, because next time, the next person might be you!

Comment: @MichaelHampton, the thing is that i will have to waste time that i don't have scripting it and looking at the configurations.
But i will think about your advice and try to see the possibility of a script in case i have to start from scratch.